# Why doesn't the Union function in LINQ remove duplicate entries?

Tags: vb.net, linq, union

I'm using VB .NET and I know that Union normally works ByRef but in VB, Strings are generally processed as if they were primitive datatypes.

Consequently, here's the problem:

```
Sub Main()
    Dim firstFile, secondFile As String(), resultingFile As New StringBuilder

    firstFile = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText(My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.Desktop & "\1.txt").Split(vbNewLine)
    secondFile = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText(My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.Desktop & "\2.txt").Split(vbNewLine)

    For Each line As String In firstFile.Union(secondFile)
        resultingFile.AppendLine(line)
    Next

    My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText(My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.Desktop & "\merged.txt", resultingFile.ToString, True)
End Sub
```

1.txt contains:
a
b
c
d
e

2.txt contains:
b
c
d
e
f
g
h
i
j

After running the code, I get:
a
b
c
d
e
b
f
g
h
i
j

Any suggestions for making the Union function act like its mathematical counterpart?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Linq `Union` does perform as you want it to. Ensure your input files are correct (e.g. one of the lines may contain a space before the newline) or `Trim()` the strings after splitting?

```
var list1 = new[] { "a", "s", "d" };
var list2 = new[] { "d", "a", "f", "123" };
var union = list1.Union(list2);
union.Dump(); // this is a LinqPad method
```

In [linqpad](http://www.linqpad.net/), the result is `{"a", "s", "d", "f", "123" }`

Answer (score 2):

I think you want to use the Distinct function.  At then end of your LINQ statement do `.Distinct();`

```
var distinctList = yourCombinedList.Distinct();
```

Similar to a 'SELECT DISTINCT' in SQL :)

Comment: Distinct shouldn't be required after Linq's Union method

Comment: You are correct, I should have said, 'combined' list in my example.  Updating it to reflect that thanks.