# LINQ Union vs SQL Union

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, linq

I am having relationship between `Users` and `UsersProjects`. `UserProjects.UserId` references to `Users.UserId`

I want to find User which is in `UserProjects` and `UserProject` has `UsreProjects.ProjectId == 4`. And then union the rest of Users to this table.

In fact I want to change some propierties of User which `UserProject = 4`.

In MSSQL, just to test I have below query

```
Select U.UserId 
from Users U
Join UserProjects UP
On U.UserId = up.UserId
Where up.ProjectId = 4
Union
Select U.UserId  From Users U
```

I am not changing any properties. Anyway as the result it shows me whole users as it should.

But now using the same query with changing properties result more users than I ave.

```
 var usrs = ((from users in context.Users
                             join userProj in context.UserProjects
                             on users.UserId equals userProj.UserId
                             where userProj.ProjectId == projectId
                             select new ProjectUsersDTO
                             {
                                 UserName = users.Name,
                                 Rate = users.RatePerHour,
                                 UserId = users.UserId,
                                 alreadyInProject = true
                             })
                             .Union(from users in context.Users
                                    select new ProjectUsersDTO
                                    {
                                        UserName = users.Name,
                                        Rate = users.RatePerHour,
                                        UserId = users.UserId,
                                        alreadyInProject = false
                                    }))
                               .ToList();
                    return usrs;
```

How does it go when UNION doesn't allow duplicates?

Thanks in adivce!

Comment: Your LINQ Union should result in unique objects as long as the objects are comparable and equal. Your objects in question are ProjectUsersDTO. I think you will need to implement an IEquatable interface on this object for the union to work as you intend. Also, your value sets are slightly different since the "alreadyInProject" [sic] properties are not identical. If your IEquatable implementation ignores this property, this won't matter.

Comment: You are using the IEnumerable.Union since you project to a DTO before the union. If you want the distinct to be performed by the database, then you need to postpone the projection to the DTO until after the union. So project to an anonymous type in both queries, then the union, then add an AsEnumerable() call, then project to the DTO, then perform ToList().

Comment: @Maarten I was just about to add that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> LINQ Union vs SQL Union

They are equivalent.

> But now using the same query with changing properties result more users than I ave.

It's **not the same** query. In the first (SQL) query you select (include) only one field (`UserId`) while in the second (LINQ) you include a couple fields, one of them being for sure **different**. Since the `Union` uses all the included fields as criteria whether the item is unique, it's normal the second query to return more items.

With that being said, let see how to solve the concrete issue. Looks like you don't need `Union` at all. Normally you should have a **navigation properties**, so a simple query like this should do the job (assuming the navigation property is called `Projects`):

```
var query =
    from user in context.Users
    select new ProjectUsersDTO
    {
        UserName = user.Name,
        Rate = user.RatePerHour,
        UserId = user.UserId,
        alreadyInProject = user.Projects.Any(userProj => userProj.ProjectId == projectId)
    };

var result = query.ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

Difference of behavior between `SQL UNION` (which performs an implicit `DISTINCT`) and `LINQ Union` (which required an explicit `Distinct()`) is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1250588/why-doesnt-the-union-function-in-linq-remove-duplicate-entries).

So, for your particular case, just apply a `Distinct()` to your query.

Comment: The link you provided doesnt explain the differences at all. It talks about in-memory linq, not ef or l2s.

Answer (score 0):

Uniqueness/no duplicates is based upon the complete record/ProjectUsersDTO instance.

The users in project 4 (or whatever the value for variable projectId) will be twice in the result, one time with alreadyInProject = true and another time with alreadyInProject = false.
The first select selects only the users in the project and the second one selects all users (including the ones in the project). They are considered as different records because the value for alreadyInProject is different, so both versions will be in the output.

I'm not sure what you want, but I assume you want a list of all users with an indication whether or not they are in the project with the given projectId.
You could use this code

```
var usrs = (from users in context.Users
            join userProj in context.UserProjects
            on users.UserId equals userProj.UserId
            select new ProjectUsersDTO
            {
                UserName = users.Name,
                Rate = users.RatePerHour,
                UserId = users.UserId,
                alreadyInProject = (userProj.ProjectId == projectId)
            })
            .ToList();
return usrs;
```